# Recursively require all properties for TypeScript object

Tags: typescript, types

The `Required` type utility only shallowly requires all properties on a TypeScript object type. Is there a way to also recursively require all properties for nested objects?

```js
type Example = {
  a?: true,
  b?: {
    a?: true,
    b?: true,
  }
}

type RequiredExample = DeepRequire<Example>
```

My bad approach so far:

```js
export type DeepRequired<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends object
    ? T[P] extends Function ? T[P] : DeepRequired<T[P]>
    : T[P]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it like this

```js
type DeepRequired<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[K]>
}
```

[Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBAREIICUQCOArgJYwgAmAPACoB8CAvAgN7AIIDaA0giQHYIA1iGRQAZghoBdALQB+AFyZseQqXLUaPaXWABfYMBRoEAZTgwARlCgAbJgnwBjWNQDOlgQHMANAht7EABDQQAfJxBXGA8vfj8A2zsQ-jo9YFd+TwRyAmUsHHxiMkoqC2skhmY2DmClJBgiEF92APqajgQ65Usmls62nsbm1sNDDKgsxFyAJnzVIo1S8sC7KtZW4KG+1qtlDtrtkYG9hp2OMaMgA)

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration! Here's what I ended up with based on your code.

```typescript
type RecursivelyRequired<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?:
  Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends object ? RecursivelyRequired<T[K]> : T[K]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the inspiration provided by Teneff & others, here's the final result.

```js
type DeepRequire<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?:
  Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends object ? DeepRequire<T[K]> : T[K]
}
```